# Simplify forEach Consumer

Tags: java, lambda, simplify, functional-interface

I have two interfaces :

```
public interface Observer<T extends Observer<T>> {
    List<T> getObserverChildren();

    default void forEachObserver(Consumer<T> consumer) {
        this.getObserverChildren().forEach(consumer);
    }
}
```

and

```
public interface ChronoObserver extends Observer<ChronoObserver> {
    default void updateTime(int seconds, int minutes) {
        this.forEachObserver(observerChild -> observerChild.updateTime(seconds, minutes));
    }
}
```

I would like to simplify the call to the method "forEachObserver" by having something more like that :

```
default void forEachObserver(TheType myMethod) { // myMethod may be any method like updateTime(...), updateDay(...), etc...
        this.getObserverChildren().forEach(observerChild -> observerChild.myMethod);
}
```

so that i could call it with something like this :

```
this.forEachObserver(myMethod); // myMethod could be updateTime(seconds, minutes), updateDay(day), etc...
```

Is there any way to simplify it like this ? Thanks

Comment: Use a shorter variable name.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.

```
void forEachObserver(Consumer<Observer> cons) { // myMethod may be any method like
                                        // updateTime(...), updateDay(...),etc...
        getObserverChildren().forEach((child)->cons.accept(child));
    }
}


forEachObserver((t)->t.myMethod());
```

e.g.

```
forEachObserver((t)->t.updateTime(10,20));
```

Comment: thanks, why didn't you use "forEach(cons)" directly ?

Comment: Probably should have.   I had it in my tests.  Probably just forgot to change it.

Comment: I would prefer to be able to do something with a method reference (this would be maximum simplification). For example this : 
default void forEachObserverChild(BiConsumer<T, Integer> consumer, Integer arg2) {
        this.forEachObserverChild(arg1 -> consumer.accept(arg1, arg2));
 }
used this way : 
this.forEachObserverChild(ChronoObserver::updateMinutes, minutes)

but I would like something more generic than that (this example only work for single Integer parameter methods). It would be the perfect answer if it could be "infinite" number of parameters of any type. Thanks for your help!